# fn_trace_gettable() reports an error

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017, trace

The following code returns some rows with `[Error] = 2`

> ```
> SELECT
>  v1.[name] as EventName, tr.TextData, tr.HostName, tr.ApplicationName, tr.LoginName, tr.SPID, tr.Duration, 
>  tr.StartTime, tr.EndTime, tr.Reads, tr.Writes, tr.CPU, tr.ServerName, tr.Error, tr.ObjectName, tr.RowCounts
> FROM 
>  sys.trace_events as v1
>  INNER JOIN fn_trace_gettable(@v_path, DEFAULT) as tr ON tr.EventClass = v1.trace_event_id 
> WHERE 
>  tr.TextData IS NOT NULL AND
>  (tr.EndTime > @v_maxEndTime OR @v_maxEndTime IS NULL)
>  OPTION(RECOMPILE);
> ```

Where can I see the list of error codes for `fn_trace_gettable` to understand what this one means?

Comment: Where do you execute this code? What is your full server version (the result of select @@version)?

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2017 (RTM-CU15) (KB4498951) - 14.0.3162.1 (X64)   May 15 2019 19:14:30   Copyright (C) 2017 Microsoft Corporation  Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows Server 2016 Datacenter 10.0 <X64> (Build 14393: ) (Hypervisor)

Answer (score 1):

The most common error codes when tracing regular query execution will be `0`, `1` or `2`.

```
0 = OK, 1 = Error, 2 = Abort
```

[Source](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/3504/sql-server-profiler-data-columns-explained/)

In your case, error code `2 = abort`, meaning that a query was cancelled due to such things as a timeout or a user action.

You can test this by starting a trace, running a query and stopping it before execution end:

[image]

The official definition shows that other error messages might be shown dependent on which events you select:

[image]

The same is true for the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/sql-trace/sql-trace?view=sql-server-ver15#use-data-columns-to-describe-returned-events) on traces.

[image]

These errors and their definition can be found in:

```
SELECT * 
FROM sys.sysmessages;
```

---

Testing this could be done by selecting error events:

[image]

Running a divide by zero query to produce an error:

[image]

Finding the exception error number:

[image]

And then querying `sys.sysmessages`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM sys.sysmessages
where error = 8134;
```

Result:

[image]